# How can I edit my token claims after after it was created?

Tags: oauth-2.0, token, identityserver4, access-token, claims

I have this application where I get token after I login. I am using Identity Server 4.

I'm using authorization grant type as of the moment.

The role/s of the user are specified as claims in the Token.
However, I want to switch roles whenever I want after logging in.
Meaning, I want to edit the token claims, remove the other role when the other is in used.

I want it because of our security. Detecting the other one would make the api calls fail.
Is there anything that I can do?

Answer (score 1):

This feels like a data design question, in terms of what goes into access tokens:

- Should you issue all possible roles for the user as an array claim?
- Should you also include a 'can_change_role' claim, since this feels like a privilege that not all users would have?

I would aim to issue the token once, then your app should take actions that are within the control of your APIs and do not require OAuth customization.

Also, when claims are highly domain specific and change often, it can be best to exclude them from access tokens and look them up from your API's own data instead.

It feels a little like you might be getting into the area of impersonation, which can be a tricky topic in OAuth. A simpler step forward may be to just improve the token data.